# What if my Filipina girlfriend is denied admission

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, filipino-citizens, denial-of-entry

So my Filipina girlfriend wants to visit me in America and I know that that on a US B-2 Tourist Visa she can stay for a maximum of 6 months.

Well, I want her here for approximately 5 months, but I am afraid that she may be denied admission into US even though I will be financing her and plan to go to her county and marry her.

If she is denied admission do I get a refund for her ticket?

Comment: If somebody is refused entry to a country, they don't get their ticket refunded, no. Quite the opposite: they have to pay for their ticket back home.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - well, they can *refuse* to pay for a ticket home and the airline will still have to return them, but the airline of course can try and collect the costs afterwards, which might be unlikely if they spent nearly all their savings getting there in the first place. Most likely if they have a return ticket the airline will just change the date (perhaps for free) rather than requiring them to buy a new ticket.

Comment: Thank you so much, and it is rather unfortunate that I have to make multiple posts and use a compound question.

Comment: Keep in mind that a major purpose of this site is to collect information that can be useful to people in the future, not just to the person asking it today.  It's quite possible that a future visitor would want to know *one* of the things you are asking.  It's less likely that they would want to know *all* of them.  So by separating your questions, you are making the answers more useful and easier for people in the future.

Comment: Very good point and forgive me for my presumptuous rudeness.

Comment: Following the edit I have voted to re-open this question.

Answer (score 4):

No, as mentioned in comments, you won't get any refund for flights if denied admission. If you wish to insure against such an event, you would have to find an insurance company that would provide such a policy. I've not heard of one though.

To minimise the chances of your girlfriend being denied admission, I would suggest that you ensure that her visa application contains all the answers that could possibly come up in questions at the border interview. i.e. for purpose of visit, if she puts "general tourism" and only at the border interview she admits she's visiting her boyfriend, then that creates a new doubt that she may leave the country. If she instead stated that in her visa application and the visa is granted, it seems somewhat more unreasonable for the CBP agent to deny entry based on something stated and approved in the visa application. Similarly for duration of visit and other questions.

By volunteering information in the visa application, she *may* be more likely to be refused a visa, but *if* the visa is granted, she *may* be less likely to be refused entry at the border.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information and I understand now it is best to just visit her, as despite me telling her that I want to marry her in her country then go through the K-3 spousal visa process, she is too hard set about living with me in America as soon as possible. I do want her here with me but I would rather go through the least complicated process.

Comment: @TyrellGardner One of the questions they may ask her at the border is if she's ever met you. Her saying no, will not be favourable

Comment: The fact that she is so determined to come to US as soon as possible instead of actually meeting you is a huge red flag in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, when a person is refused entry to a country, they do not get a refund on their ticket. Quite the opposite, in fact: they have to pay for their ticket home. This may involve paying a fee to change the existing ticket, or it may involve buying a completely new ticket.

It is always the passenger's responsibility to make sure they meet the entry conditions of the country they are travelling to. Airlines will check that the passenger has the required documentation, because they also get fined when people are refused entry. However, the airline has been contracted to take the passenger to the airport, which they have done, so there are no grounds for a refund.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will definitely not get any refund on any airfare.

Further, unless she obtains a certain type of Visa, residence, work, transit, etc., the airline may even require a round trip ticket purchase.

If she is denied admission, that is how she will pay for the return.

Comment: The plan was, presumably, to buy a return ticket anyway (at least, the asker says that his girlfriend will visit for five months; implicitly, she will then return home and a return ticket is usually the most sensible way to do that).

Comment: Thank you for the comment and of course, I intend for her to return home. For many reasons and some being either very obvious or can easily be guessed, I am going to her country and marry her.